# Wait for multiple audio files to finish loading then play them in sequence

Tags: javascript, html, audio

HTML5 has `onloadeddata` for calling a method when the audio is loaded, and you can add listeners for a callback when it's finished playing. But how would it work with multiple audio files? How do you trigger a call when **all** of them are loaded?

Answer (score 4):

I would use

```
if(music.buffered.end == music.duration && music2.duration.end == music2.duration){
    music.play();
    music2.play();
}
```

to play both at the same time when they both are fully loaded.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a setTimeout for like 6 seconds then call the files:

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
       file1.play();
       file2.play();
       file3.play();
    }
, 6000);
```